# Create Hover effecto on menu

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I`m trying to achieve a menu that when hovering on each item on the menu the image placed on top of the page changes. So far, I don´t know how to do that hover effect,I placed the image on the first div section, but I imagine I have to put the rest of the images, but I don´t know how to link every item of the menu to each image. Everything else is working fine.

Is it possible to do this with CSS or the only way is to do it with javascript

In this page you can see an example that is very close to what I want.
[Laura Meroni](http://www.laurameroni.com/en/stories)

This is the html for the menu:

```
<div class="header-top"> 
    <img src="https://leyandlaw.callibree.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/IMAGENES-MENU.jpg" class="responsive" alt="">
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://leyandlaw.callibree.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/leyandlay-abogados.jpg" class="logo-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <nav class="col-2" >
        <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Colaboración con la prensa</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Valores L&L</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-3">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Especialidades</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Confían en nosotros</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Desayunos L&L</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Equipo</a>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS I have:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body { 
  background: #fff;
}
.header-top{
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.responsive{
width: 100%;
}
.responsive-fondo {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: -20;
}
li a:hover> .responsive-fondo {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.logo-responsive{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
}
.col-1{
flex-grow: 3;
}
.col-2{
flex-grow: 2;
margin-top: 100px;
}
.col-3{
flex-grow: 2;
margin-top: 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px
}
li a {
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "Raleway" sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Manuel Pavía do you want the interaction to be that when the user hovers on the anchor like

```
<a href="#">Valores L&L</a>
```

that the image right after it gets effected?

if so you can do:

```
a:hover + img { //img stuff }
```

Comment: Not that. The image is on top. When you hover de menu down, the image changes on every item, showing a different image each time. This is the design so far: https://pasteboard.co/HLtXQyU.png

Comment: @ManuelPavía Then i would recommend some basic js to swap the image

Answer (score 0):

use `class.hover {/path/to/image}`
and why not try using bootstrap, it easier implementing any css with bootstrap